# How to change widget preview image programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget

I have widget witch changes it's icon according to settings. It's working for widget icon but I don't know if it possible to do for previewImage.

Is it possible to change widget preview image programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is impossible for appwidgets. Only xml resources are accepted:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#preview

but you may want to try different drawable sizes:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range